# Why do I need clear() stringstream after reading from it in a function?

Tags: c++

Why should I write `ss.clear()` in function `Read()` to be able to write to `stringstream ss` again?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void Read(istream& ss, string& s)
{
    while(getline(ss, s)){
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    ss.clear();
}

int main()
{
    stringstream ss;
    string s;
    ss << "A\nB\n";
    Read(ss, s);
    ss << "C\n";
    Read(ss, s);
}
```

If `ss.clear()` is commented, the third line is not written to `cout`.

Comment: @gas128 yes there is

Comment: `clear()` is only needed if your stream is in an error state.  It informs the stream that you have recognized and addressed whatever put it in that error state.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: you are right. In the base class to clear the error not to clear the stream of its content. I removed my spam.

Answer (score 4):

When you call

```
ss << "A\nB\n";
Read(ss, s);
```

The first call to `getline` extracts `A`, the second extracts `B`, and it is important to understand that you can only know that you are at the end of the stream after `getline` has been called once more. The third call to `getline` fails, there is no 3rd line in the stream, and the loop stops. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

> If no characters were extracted for whatever reason (not even the discarded delimiter), getline sets failbit and returns.

Once the `failbit` is set, the stream cant be used to extract more. Calling `clear` resets the error bits so you can continue using the stream.